# scanf getchar function is skipped

Tags: c

A very simple question. Why scanf is skipped in the first while loop.
I have tried it by using getchar() and the result is same. getchar is skipped.

If you guys dont understand what I'm talking about you can tried compile it and you guys will understand what i'm asking about.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct rec{
    int num;
    char pref[16];
    float point;
    struct rec* next;
}rec;

void dataInput(float*,char*);
rec* insertNode(rec*);

int main(){

    int i=1;
    rec* entr,*pt = NULL;
    entr = (rec*) malloc(sizeof(rec));
    entr->num = i;
    dataInput(&entr->point,entr->pref);
    entr->next = NULL;
    char key;
    i++;

    while(1){

        printf("Continue ? If YES press 'y',or NO press 'n'\n");
        key = getchar();
        if(key == 'n')break;
        else if(key == 'y'){
            if(!pt){
                pt = insertNode(entr);
            }else{
                pt = insertNode(pt);
            }
            dataInput(&pt->point,pt->pref);
            pt->num = i;
            i++;
            continue;
        }else{
            printf("Wrong key! Please Press again! \n");
        }

    }

    pt = entr;
    while(pt){

        printf("num : %d, pref :  %s, point: %.1f\n",
                pt->num,
                pt->pref,
                pt->point);
        pt = pt->next;
    }

    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void dataInput(float* point,char* pref){

    printf("Input Point\t : ");
    scanf("%f",point);

    printf("Input Pref\t : ");
    scanf("%s",pref);
}

rec* insertNode(rec* current){
    rec* newnode = (rec*)malloc(sizeof(rec));
    current->next = newnode;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    return newnode;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because `scanf` will leave a `'\n'` (endline) symbol in the input buffer. This symbol will be consumed by `getchar` at the first iteration of this `while(1)` loop.

Comment: Yes! it works!!
if(key == '\n'){ key = getchar(); }
after i added it. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

`getchar()` leaves a newline character in the input buffer which is read by the subsequent scanf().

You can use solve this by using a leading space in the scanf:

```
scanf(" %c ...", &c,..);
```

which tells the scanf to ignore all whitespace characters. Or use another `getchar()` right after the first getchar() to consume the newline.

Comment: Omg this second option you suggested has been the *ONLY WORKING OPTION* for me. I tried _everything_ mentioned in the nearly 15 similar questions. Adding a space before the %c didn't work, adding a \n after the %c didn't work, using fflush(stdin) didn't work, gets, getchar, and scanf all had the same problem... Ugh... Do you know why this is?

Comment: Could be due to any subsequent scanf/fgets calls etc. Can't tell without looking at the code. But I'd suggest reading this: http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html and avoid scanf() altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Just use another `getchar()` after the `scanf()` to consume the newline character.