# How can I calculate the moving average of the array?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

In Question, When an `array X` of size n and a `degree k` are input,
Write a program that calculates the `k-th` moving average of `array X`.
The kth-order moving average of the `array X` consisting of primitive data values is the average of the last k elements up to the i-th point of `X`.

That is, `A [i] = (X [i-k + 1] + X [i-k + 2] + ... + X [i]) / k`.

If the number of the preceding element (including itself) is smaller than k,
Calculate as an average.

For example, if array X is as follows and `k` is `3`, `X = 1 3 2 10 6 8`

The third moving average is as follows.

```
A = 1 2 2 5 6 8 A [1] = (1 + 3) / 2, A [2] = (1 + 3 + 2) / 3
```

However, the program must have the execution time of O (n), not O (nk).
Round off the decimal point in the average calculation and obtain it as an integer.
For exact rounding, do not use% .f, but round it using the int property.

```
int main()
{
  int i, n1, k;
  int *array1;
  scanf("%d", &n1);
  array1 = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*n1);
  scanf("%d", &k);
  for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
  {
    scanf("%d", &array1[i]);
  }

double tmp = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
{
    tmp += array1[i];

    if (i >= k)     
    {
        tmp -= array1[i - k];
    }
    if (i >= k - 1) 
    {
        double average = tmp / k;
        printf("%2lld ", llrint(average));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program does not work because the problem is not understood.
I would like to know how to solve it.

add) Thank you for answer but the output required by the problem is as follows.

```
Input : 9 4 (n = 9, k = 3)
         2 7 4 5 6 8 2 8 13
 Output : 2 5 4 5 6 6 5 6 8
```

Comment: Given `int *array1;` and `array1 = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*n1);`, then `sizeof(array1)` is wrong.  That's the size of the *pointer*, not the array it points to.

Comment: I ma pretty sure at leas one of the problems is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473693/scanf-getchar-function-is-skipped)

Comment: Also, you need to test the return value from `scanf()`.  You have no idea if any of those calls worked or not.

Comment: `for (int k = 0; k < i; k++)
    {
        tmp = array1[k];
    }` doesn't make sense. Did you mean to use `+=` instead of `=`?

Comment: One obvious bug is that you are using the same loop variable `i` in both an outer and an inner loop. Another bug is the use of `i < sizeof(array1)` as a loop termination condition, because `sizeof(array1)` is the size of a pointer in bytes, not the length of the array. I think you need to replace `sizeof(array1)` with `n1`.

Comment: To move from `O(nk)` to `O(n)` you need to use the fact that `ave(i+1) = ave(i) + (array[i] - array[i-k])/k` for `i >= k`. Se the answer by @KaidulIslam.

Comment: FYI, in c99 you have [variable length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), so `scanf("%d", &n1); int array1[n1];` will work, (though might cause issues for very large arrays on some compilers)

Comment: Can you draw a picture that represents the concept of moving average of order k to the best of your understanding? How many of those are in an array of size n?

Comment: @n.m. [Moving averages are well-know, well-defined quantities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average).

Answer (score 0):

After Modifying your code

```
int main()
 {
    int i, n1, k;
    int *array1, *array2;
    scanf("%d", &n1);
    array1 = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*n1);
    scanf("%d", &k);
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &array1[i]);
    }

    double tmp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
    {
        tmp += array1[i];
        // now tmp contains exactly k + 1 elements sum
        // so subtract elements outside of k sized window(leftmost element)
        if(i >= k) {
            tmp -= array1[i - k];
        }
        if(i >= k - 1) {
            double average = tmp / k;
            printf("%lf\n", average);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't you have to divide by a value other than `k` before you reach the kth average?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for pointing out. I left a serious bug.

Comment: The moving average of the first 1, 2, … k-1 items is defined — it just isn't defined by dividing by k.

Comment: OP does post "For exact rounding, do not use% .f," so I guess `printf("%lf\n", average);` sneakily meets that restriction.  Consider `rint()` to round.