# Trying to make scanf not go to a new line in a for loop (C Programming)

Tags: c, arrays

Sorry if my English is poor. What I'm trying to do is get the scanf to be entered on the same line. For example `Enter value: 1 6 8 9 4 1 2 8 5` and it to be separated by a space. Then the numbers to be stored in an array. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a[10], smallest, i;

    printf("Random\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);

    smallest = a[0];

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
    {
        if (a[i] < smallest)
        {
            smallest = a[i];
        }
    }
    printf("\nSmallest Element : %d\n", smallest);

}
```

Thanks for any help!

Edit: I'm trying to make the user enter 9 numbers which are stored in the array using scanf but when entering the numbers the scanf goes to a new line for example:

`> 5`

`> 6` and so on what I want is for them to enter the number numbers on the same line with a space in between like this `Enter value: 1 6 8 9 4 1 2 8 5`

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)` --> `for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)`

Comment: what is your question need to explain

Comment: The user will enter the values and terminate the input by pressing Enter. Upon pressing Enter, the terminal will give the line to the program. The program now processes the line, as you are doing (but maybe use `" %d"` for format - note there is a space before `%d`

Comment: Your program will take input the way you just wanted. If you input the numbers, space separated, it already can. `%d` modifier ignores ' '(spaces) and '\n'(new lines)

Comment: So I got it to work but I have to manually press space instead of the program doing it for me. But I can go for example `Enter value: 5 6 65 64 56 4 8 56 5 4 69 5 8 4 2 8 5` which I don't want it too. I'm trying to restrict it to only 9 integers.

Comment: Then you will have to do some input parsing. eg. you will have to take the input as `char` using `%c` and then check the characters accordingly

Comment: @Ultraviolet is there anyway to add a space in between the scanf's so I don't manually have to do it.

Comment: yes. I am writing an answer.

Comment: Is a user enters `"1 2 3 4"` on one line, what should happen? Is a user enters `"1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12"` what should happen?

Answer (score 2):

Scanf will await for a complete line. I suggest you take your input as a string then use [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) to extract the values and then assign.

**Edit**: You could use the scanf like that:

```
scanf( "%d %d ...", &a[0], &a[1]...); //as many values you're to assign
```

However, I prefer the method I proposed initially. Keep in mind scanf is derived from "scan formatted". You'll also have to handle the result from the scanf, it returns the number of values successfully filled.

Comment: So is there no way to for example move each scanf to the same line?

Answer (score 1):

you can `scanf` all numbers in one statement: `scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d", &a[0], &a[1], &a[2], &a[3], &a[4], &a[5], &a[6], &a[7], &a[8], &a[9]);`
This will let you scan 10 numbers with spaces between them, without the need to hit enter every time

*note that I scanned 10 ints, because your array can store 10 ints, while your loop only scans 9... (to fix it, change **i < 9 to i < 10** as Sourav Ghosh suggested)*

Comment: I tried doing this but I don't get the getchar() bit

Comment: @ReganKelly here is a better explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13473734/3512538

Comment: I looked at it and I still don't get it sorry.

Comment: @ReganKelly nevermind. I edited my answer. Ignore that last part