# Reading 2 characters in C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char a,b;  
  printf("Enter Character 1 ");
  scanf("%c",&a);
  printf("Enter Character 2");
  scanf("%c",&b);
  printf("%c%c",a,b);
}
```

find output of program. It is not taking 2 characters.

Comment: When you ran it, how many keys did you press, which ones, and in what order?

Comment: If you want to read only one char, why you are using scanf? Check get char http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/getchar/

Comment: Even consecutive getchar() with enter will give the same result. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473693/scanf-getchar-function-is-skipped). fgets() is the best alternative for scanf() in most case

Answer (score 0):

When you enter the first character; 
The character Ascii value is placed in the variable A .
Then you press enter and the ascii value of enter thats 13 is placed in the second variable.
So B should be 13.

In order to run this program use **flushall()** library function..

```
int main() { 
    char a,b; 
    printf("Enter Character 1 "); 
    scanf("%c",&a);
    flushall();
    printf("Enter Character 2"); 
    scanf("%c",&b); 
    printf("%c%c",a,b); 
    return 0;
}
```

You could also use the standard Library function **scanf()**
Write something like:

```
Scanf(" %c",&variablename);
```

The space before the %c tells the compiler to skip any whitespace (if any).

Comment: flushall() is not a standard function