# my do-while is terminating instead of continuing my C program

Tags: c

When I'm trying to run without debugging the code everything runs smooth but as soon as I press `Y` so I can continue inputting numbers it terminates (gotta say I need help)

```
int main() {
    int a;
    char c;

    do {
        puts("dwse mou enan arithmo: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &a);

        if (a > 0) {
            if (a % 2 == 0)
                printf("the number %d is even \n", a);
            else
                printf("the number %d is odd \n", a);
        } else {
            printf("the program won't run with negative numbers \n");
        }

        printf("if you want to proceed press y or Y :");
        c = getchar();
        getchar();
    } while (c == 'y' || c == 'Y');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What value is in `c`?  What if you add parentheses to the expression for the `do-while` loop?

Comment: This is almost certainly the [usual headache with mixing `scanf` and `getchar`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473693/scanf-getchar-function-is-skipped).  `scanf` doesn't consume the newline after the number, so `c` winds up having the value `'\n'`, which is not equal to `'y'` or `'Y'`.  Instead use `fgets` to read entire lines at a time, and convert text to machine numbers with `strtol` and friends.

Comment: Also, functions such as `scanf_s()` are from Annex K of the C standard.  They are optional, so they're not portable.  Not only that, [this is the state of Annex K](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm#tc): "we propose that Annex K be either removed from the next revision of the C standard, or deprecated and then removed.".  The Microsoft implementation is even worse: "As a result of the numerous deviations from the specification the Microsoft implementation cannot be considered conforming or portable."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character read by `getchar()` is the pending newline that was typed after the number but was not consumed by `scanf_s`.

You should consume this pending newline before reading the next character for the continuation test, which can be done easily in `scanf` with a space before the `%c` conversion specification:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a;
    char c;

    for (;;) {
        printf("dwse mou enan arithmo: ");
        if (scanf_s("%d", &a) != 1)
            break;

        if (a >= 0) {
            if (a % 2 == 0)
                printf("the number %d is even\n", a);
            else
                printf("the number %d is odd\n", a);
        } else {
            printf("the program does not accept negative numbers\n");
        }

        printf("if you want to proceed press y or Y: ");
        if (scanf_s(" %c", &c) != 1 || (c != 'y' && c != 'Y'))
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It works!!! Thank you very much for the correct code and the things i should look out for next time i do something similar.