# getchar() not waiting for input and jumping directly to next line

Tags: c, scanf, getchar

getchar() not waiting for input and jumping directly to next line. There is some mismatch between scanf and getchar I think but not able to make out what is it exactly.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main()
{

char ch;
int n1,n2;

printf("Enter the operation of your choice\n");
printf("a. add\ts. subtact\nm. multiply\td. divide\nq. quit\n");

while((ch=getchar())!='q')
{
 printf("\nEnter 1st number:\n");
    if(scanf("%d",&n1)!=1)
    {
        printf("Please enter an integer value.\n");
        continue;
    }
       printf("Enter 2nd number:\n");
    if(scanf("%d",&n2)!=1)
    {
        printf("Please enter an integer value.\n");
        continue;
    }  

 switch(ch)
    {
        case 'a':
        { printf(" %d + %d = %d\n",n1,n2,n1+n2);
          break;  
        }

        case 's':
        {
            printf(" %d - %d = %d\n",n1,n2,n1-n2);
            break;
        }

        case 'm':
        {
            printf(" %d * %d = %d\n",n1,n2,n1*n2);
            break;
        }

         case 'd':
        {

            if(n2!=0)
            {
            printf(" %d / %d = %f\n",n1,n2,(float)n1/n2);
            break;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Enter a non-zero number for n2\n");
                continue;
            }

            break;
        }

    }

 printf("Enter the operation of your choice\n");
 printf("a. add\ts. subtact\nm. multiply\td. divide\nq. quit\n");
  }
  printf("Bye.");
 }
```

OUTPUT:

Enter the operation of your choice

a. add  s. subtact

m. multiply     d. divide

q. quit

a

Enter 1st number:

50

Enter 2nd number:

25

50 + 25 = 75

Enter the operation of your choice

a. add  s. subtact

m. multiply     d. divide

q. quit

Enter 1st number:

Comment: getchar reads also white spaces. as for example the new line character '\n' that corresponds to the entered key Enter. Use instead scanf( " %c", &ch );

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scanf getchar function is skipped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473693/scanf-getchar-function-is-skipped)

Answer (score 0):

your *getchar* reads the newline and other spaces you enter when you give the value read by the *scanf*, you need to bypass these spaces

just replace

> ```
> while((ch=getchar())!='q')
> ```

by

```
 while ((scanf(" %c", &ch) == 1) && (ch != 'q'))
```

notice the space before '%', this is thank to it the spaces including newline are bypassed