# To take an integer input after character I used " %c " but does not run when no integer given as input

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int value;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *push(struct node *head, int x)
{
    struct node *v = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node *));
    v->next = head;
    v->value = x;
    return v;
}

struct node *pop(struct node *head)
{
    return head->next;
}

void print(struct node *head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("NULL\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while (head != NULL)
        {
            printf("%d", head->value);
            if (head->next != NULL)
            {
                printf(" ");
            }
            head = head->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct node *head = NULL;
    char c;
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf(" %c ", &c);
        if (c == 'a')
        {
            int x;
            scanf("%d", &x);
            head = push(head, x);
            print(head);
        }
        else if (c == 'd')
        {
            head = pop(head);
            print(head);
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, I take integer input when the character input is 'a' but when the character input is 'd' I don't have to take input as I am deleting the first element of the stack. I referred [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13473767/16669839). But now I am unable to handle the case of 'd' where I don't have to take integer input again. Please rectify my code.

**Edit:**

As mentioned in the replies to my query if I remove the whitespace from %c, then 'a' and 'd' mention in my code works properly but the for loop does not run 4 times instead only runs 2 times. Thus the input I and output are as follows:

```
4
a 1
1
d
NULL
```

Here, (4,a 1,d) are inputs and (1 and NULL) outputs. After printing NULL the program terminates but ideally, it should have taken two more inputs. Please rectify my code.

Comment: Please don't use trailing space in `scanf` format strings. That often won't work as you expect. What happens with is is that it makes `scanf` read and discard all trailing space until it can read something which *isn't* a space. Which means you must add some non-space input to satisfy `scanf`.

Comment: After your update: we are not telling you to remove *all* the whitespace from `" %c".  Just the *trailing* whitespace.

Comment: Wrong: `"%c"`.  Wrong: `" %c "`.  Right: `" %c"`.  (Is this nonsensically confusing?  Most assuredly yes.  `scanf` sucks, and its infliction on beginning C programmers is a decadeslong pattern of serial abuse.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the trailing spaces in your `scanf` formats.  When a `scanf` format contains a space, scanf will read (and discard) whitespace characters until it gets a non-whitespace character (at which point it will leave that non-whitespace character as the next character to be read by the next pattern or call).

The net result of this is that when you have an input line like <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, the `scanf(" %c ",` call won't return until you enter *another* line with some non-whitespace characters (which will be left for the next scanf call to read).

Simply delete those trailing spaces in the formats and all should be fine.  The *leading* spaces are necessary to ignore any whitespace (such a newline from a preceeding command) prior to the command character.

Comment: But if I don't use the space after %c then the for loop will run less times while taking two inputs (i.e. when someone presses a and 1). So could you please tell me the right way to take the input so that the for loop runs the prescribed number of times and I am able to take both kinds of inputs?

Comment: @imk, This answer did tell you the right way.  If not good enough, append to code exact input used, output seen and output expected.

Comment: I have made appropriate changes to my query, could you please answer it now?

Comment: @imk It's safe to say that a space at the end of a `scanf` format statement is always wrong.  Whatever problem you thought you solved that way, you didn't really solve.

Comment: @imk You do need the space at the beginning of `" %c"`  But you don't need and don't want any space after.